# R-Script create additionial array prefixes. How avoid?

Tags: javascript, php, r, json

I use this R-Sript to get metadata from a FLIR Thermographie Image:

```
library(Thermimage)
inFile <- inFile
fd <- flirsettings(inFile)
```

This is executed by php to get back the result in json:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $uploadDir = 'uploads/';
    $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) {
        $exifData = exif_read_data($uploadFile);

        if ($exifData !== false) {
            $inFile = $uploadFile;

            exec("Rscript -e 'library(Thermimage); fd <- flirsettings(\"$inFile\"); cat(paste(fd$Info$Emissivity, fd$Info$IRWindowTemperature, fd$Info$IRWindowTransmission, fd$Info$RelativeHumidity, fd$Info$PlanckR1, fd$Info$PlanckB, fd$Info$PlanckF, fd$Info$PlanckO, fd$Info$PlanckR2, fd$Info$AtmosphericTransAlpha1, fd$Info$AtmosphericTransAlpha2, fd$Info$AtmosphericTransBeta1, fd$Info$AtmosphericTransBeta2, fd$Info$AtmosphericTransX, sep=\",\"))' 2>&1", $output);
            $fd= explode(",", $output[0]);

            function extractNumbersFromString($str) {
                // Verwende eine reguläre Expression, um nur Zahlen zu extrahieren
                preg_match_all('/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/', $str, $matches);
            
                // Extrahiere gefundene Zahlen aus den Matches
                $numbers = array_map(function ($match) {
                    return floatval($match);
                }, $matches[0]);
            
                return $numbers;
            }
            
            // Extrahiere Zahlenwerte aus der Beispiel-Liste
            $extractedNumbers = array_map('extractNumbersFromString', $fd);

            // Erstelle ein assoziatives Array mit den Metadaten
            $metadataArray = [
                'exifData' => $exifData,
                'fdData' => $extractedNumbers,
            ];

            // Verwende json_encode, um das kombinierte Array in JSON umzuwandeln
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($metadataArray);
        } else {
            echo 'Fehler beim Lesen der Metadaten.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Fehler beim Hochladen des Bildes.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Ungültige Anfrage.';
}
?>
```

This create the following output in JSON:

```
{
    "fdData": [
        [
            0.85
        ],
        [
-->         1,
            20274.629
        ],
        [
            1488.9
        ],
        [
            1
        ],
        [
            -4440
        ],
        [
-->         2,
            0.033941466
        ],
        [
-->         1,
            0
        ],
        [
-->         2,
            0
        ],
        [
-->         1,
            0.00318
        ],
        [
-->         2,
            0.00318
        ],
        [
            0.732
        ],
        [
            2.3
        ],
        [
            2.3
        ],
        [
            2.3
        ],
        [
            299
        ],
        [
            297
        ],
        [
            24
        ],
        [
            23
        ],
        [
            20
        ],
        [
            120
        ],
        []
    ]
}
```

On --> marked pos. you can see the addidtional prefixes. I don't know why this happends, on my oppinion this data aint exist in the metadata. Something in the R-Sricpt is doing that, but I don't have expirience in R.

Someone is having a tip, how I can aviod this?

You can test this function here: https://gracile-software.de/projects/raumzeitkrueger_neu/

Download a thermographie img her before: https://gracile-software.de/projects/raumzeitkrueger/img/FLIR0305.jpg

Comment: Can you show a sample of `$output` to show what is being processed to give the output.

Comment: If you upload a thermo-img here: https://gracile-software.de/projects/raumzeitkrueger/index.php
You can see the var_dump of $output and below a sorted outcome

Comment: (1) It makes it much more likely to get help if _you_ do that and provide it in the question. Perhaps because of this ... (2) I downloaded `FLIR0305.jpg` from your second link and submitted to the first link, and it gave me a rather odd looking return, https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqXE0.jpg, which looks like it contains some R-like expressions, but the `"list(..."` is an _interrupted_ string, cutoff at 510 characters, and it is an incomplete expression. I'm not sure what generated it, but I don't trust that it is so incomplete.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly _where_ the issue is here. You've cited three programming languages, but clearly (to me) the problem either resides in (1) _one_ of these three locally, whichever one is munging what you need; or (2) whatever language the server is using to generate full HTML each time an image is uploaded. If you're focusing on #1, then I suggest you simplify your question to just the language (and associated tag(s)) that are applicable.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe r-script is unsuitable for this if I have no experience with it. I get the same data with php exif_read.... I will try to complete the algorithm with php. thx guys!